# Change title of "Summary" section in Jekyll Github pages

Tags: html, jekyll, github-pages

I am using [this template](https://idratherbewriting.com/documentation-theme-jekyll/) to create my github website with Jekyll. Below the title, there is a small "Summary" section that summarizes the content of the page and that I find very useful. However, as my website is in German, I would like to replace "Summary" with "Zusammenfassung".

I've found this part in the html file that is responsible for producing this summary section :

```
   {% if page.summary %}
    <div class="summary">{{page.summary}}</div>
   {% endif %}
```

However I am not able to find where the title "Summary" is being defined.

Could you help me : how can I change the title of the "Summary" section ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

found it in css/customstyles.css

```
.summary:before {
    content: "Summary: ";
    font-weight: bold;
}
```